# Thermodynamic Optimization: how can I optimize with an objective function containing ThermodynamicData[]?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

In thermodynamics, there are a lot of optimization problems where the objective function containing thermodynamic property values, like "Enthalpy","Entropy", which is determined by `ThermodynamicData[]`in MMA.

Suppose I have an objective function `We`, which is a function of `pwh` with the range`0<pwh<16.11`:

```
We=((Quantity[(90 - 2.5 pwh + 0.55 pwh^2 - 0.046 pwh^3), ("Kilograms")/(
     "Seconds")]) (Quantity[1.15996*10^6, ("Joules")/("Kilograms")] - 
     ThermodynamicData["Water", 
      "Enthalpy", {"Pressure" -> Quantity[pwh, "Bars"], 
       "Quality" -> 0}]) (ThermodynamicData["Water", 
      "Enthalpy", {"Pressure" -> Quantity[pwh, "Bars"], 
       "Entropy" -> 
        ThermodynamicData["Water", 
         "Entropy", {"Pressure" -> Quantity[pwh, "Bars"], 
          "Quality" -> 1}]}] - (ThermodynamicData["Water", 
         "Enthalpy", {"Pressure" -> Quantity[pwh, "Bars"], 
          "Entropy" -> 
           ThermodynamicData["Water", 
            "Entropy", {"Pressure" -> Quantity[pwh, "Bars"], 
             "Quality" -> 1}]}] - 
        0.389213 (ThermodynamicData["Water", 
            "Enthalpy", {"Pressure" -> Quantity[pwh, "Bars"], 
             "Entropy" -> 
              ThermodynamicData["Water", 
               "Entropy", {"Pressure" -> Quantity[pwh, "Bars"], 
                "Quality" -> 1}]}] - 
           ThermodynamicData["Water", 
            "Enthalpy", {"Temperature" -> 
              Quantity[6423/20, "Kelvins"], 
             "Entropy" -> 
              ThermodynamicData["Water", 
               
               "Entropy", {"Pressure" -> Quantity[pwh, "Bars"], 
                "Quality" -> 1}]}]))/(1 + (Quantity[1.78065*10^-7, (
           "Kilograms")/(
           "Joules")]) (ThermodynamicData["Water", 
            "Enthalpy", {"Pressure" -> Quantity[pwh, "Bars"], 
             "Entropy" -> 
              ThermodynamicData["Water", 
               "Entropy", {"Pressure" -> Quantity[pwh, "Bars"], 
                "Quality" -> 1}]}] - 
           ThermodynamicData["Water", 
            "Enthalpy", {"Temperature" -> 
              Quantity[6423/20, "Kelvins"], 
             "Entropy" -> 
              ThermodynamicData["Water", 
               "Entropy", {"Pressure" -> Quantity[pwh, "Bars"], 
                "Quality" -> 1}]}]))))/(-ThermodynamicData["Water", 
     "Enthalpy", {"Pressure" -> Quantity[pwh, "Bars"], 
      "Quality" -> 0}] + 
   ThermodynamicData["Water", 
    "Enthalpy", {"Pressure" -> Quantity[pwh, "Bars"], 
     "Quality" -> 1}]);
```

`We` can represent the electric power generated by a thermodynamic process, so I would like to find the `pwh` to maximize We. And I have plotted a scatter diagram below, showing the maximum exists.

[image]

Then the question is: how can I make MMA find the maximum point and value?

Comment: Make ``we`` (avoid using capital first letter) a function of pwh: ``we[pwh_?NumericQ] := ...``. Then use ``FindMaximum[{QuantityMagnitude@we[pwh], pwh > 0}, {pwh, 4}, StepMonitor :> Echo[pwh]]`` (I have added ``StepMonitor`` so that you can follow the progress, and use 4 as an initial estimate for a quicker convergence). You can manually lower the ``AccuracyGoal`` or ``PrecisionGoal`` if you find it working for too long. Note that you have a lot of ``ThermodynamicData`` which are computationally heavy (I am not sure, but I think they might be fetching data from the server for each value).

Comment: Thanks @Domen, but the approach you suggested does not work. I have just tried, but the computation failed and the meesage returned: ```FindMaximum::grad: Evaluation of the gradient of function Experimental`NumericalFunction[{Hold[-QuantityMagnitude[we[pwh]]],Block},<<4>>,{None,None,None}] failed at {4.}.```

Comment: Which version of Mathematica are you using? Have you set the function as written above with ``we[pwh_?NumericQ] := ...``? Try clearing the definitions with ``Clear[We, we, pwh];``. Also, please compare your code with [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1e4x.png).

Comment: Thanks @Domen, my laptop is a win 10 and my version of MMA is 12.3. I have done like you did, it is also a puzzle to me why I could not reproduce the results.

Comment: Please try [copying my code](https://pastebin.com/YhAXZVu2).